# Getting base directory in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, absolute-path, base-path

I am working on a CakePHP project. Here, I have to upload a file and then move that file to a specific folder. Uploading is working well, but I can't move it to the folder I want. Is there any function or something in CakePHP to move the uploaded file ?

Currently I am using PHP's core function `move_uploaded_file()`. This function requires absolute path for both source & destination, not the `http://localhost/....`, I tried it, but it didn't work. So, do you know how do I get the `Base Directory/Absolute Path` of my application ? This would be like : `C://wamp/www/project_folder/......`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constants that Cake generates (or hands you over...) are documented in the [Global Constants and Functions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#core-definition-constants).

Using Cake's global `APP` seems the way to go (unless you don't want to move the files in the `APP/` folder).

Comment: Yeah, that constant seems to be useful for me. But, how to use the constants ? $this->App ?@JorickL

Comment: No, just by putting APP somewhere in your PHP code. It'll convert automaticaly. $var = APP . DS . 'your_folder';

Comment: And, does "DS" work for all kind of servers ? I mean, in my localhost, I need "/" and in the server "\". So, does it give the right character on all platforms, or, I have to configure it for this ?@Jorickl

Comment: As the books says: 
> Short for PHP’s DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, which is / on Linux and \ on windows.
Why don't you just give it a try and echo it somewhere in one of your views? If you `<pre>` them, you'll find out what URL you just created... ;)

Comment: Yeah, I am now using it.@Jorickl

Answer (score 3):

Add function in Controller

```
public function add() {
    $this->Model->create();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if(!empty($this->data['Model']['image']['name']))
        {
        $file=$this->data['Model']['image'];
        $ary_ext=array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
        $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], '.')), 1); //get the extension
            if(in_array($ext, $ary_ext))
            {
                move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'img/uploads/posts/' . $file['name']);
                $this->request->data['Model']['image'] = $file['name'];
            }   
        }
        if ($this->Model->save($this->request->data)) 
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your record has been saved.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        else 
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your record.');
        }
    }
}


File control in add.ctp file

echo $this->Form->input('image',array('type'=>'file'));


you can define constant in index.php file like below
/**
 *  Get Cake's root directory
 */
define('APP_DIR', 'app');
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
define('WEBROOT_DIR', 'webroot');
define('WWW_ROOT', ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use php function [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) to get the base dir of your app.

Comment: Yeah, this function is good, I am using this now. But I need a better way. @Phillaf